# Separating Assets in Unity

Tags: unity, assets, asset-management, distribution

Well, my question in rather simple - or so I hope. What I would like to do is separate my game assets in the Unity game engine into separate files for the build. This way not all the assets are in one large file, therefore making for easier and faster updates (don't have to re-download one large file if there's only a small change to one asset). How would I go about doing this? The best case solution would be if I could have everything separated during the final build, this way if I update one tree asset I don't need to update *all* tree assets, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Example Structure:

**+** A common set of assets that's loaded on startup (menu textures, trees used often, etc).

**+** A set containing trees, rocks, and other foliage.

**+** A set containing various scripts (AI scripts that would get updated frequently for example).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy indeed - you are looking for Asset Bundles, which you can read about here:  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager

In pre-2017 versions, you simply set the asset bundle at the bottom of the inspector for each asset.  In 2017, I believe there have been some changes to have a UI that allows you to set Asset Bundles with the Asset Bundle Browser:  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Browser.html

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I juts couldn't find anything on this, because - me being inexperienced with Unity - I didn't even know what to search.

Comment: All good, friend.  I've been using Unity for a while now and sometimes I'm still not sure what things are called if I don't use them a lot.  Unity's documentation can sometimes be a little hit or miss.  :)